apply to first tier tribunal (UK)
Someone was late paying their ground rent.
A court hearing was scheduled.  When the debtor turned up,  he was told that the ground rent company had recovered the debt from the debtor's mortgage company.  They had and also charged an excessive amount of legal costs, which has been added to the debtor's mortgage,
At the hearing, the debtor did not challenge the debt. No order for costs was made.
The debtor might want to go to a first-tier tribunal to challenge and recover the costs.
What form number should they use to make the application, and where can they download it?

edits that invalidate or reduce the topicality of answers are not allowed. Also, the addition of the specifics would have made this a forbitten request for specific legal advice.

In the first place, the answers given haven't understood the situation. "An argument not brought might be an argument waived" when I did in fact bring up the argument. And a lot of other stuff.  In the second place, I phrased it as a hypothetical, so that it wouldn't be giving legal advice. Someone edited  it to remove the hypothetical.  Could we put it back?  Thirdly, I haven't asked for advice on whether I would win, or how I should argue the case,  just a simple factual statement of "What form is correct (in a hypothetical case)".

According to the question there has already been a court hearing, I presume in the County Court. It sounds like the situation is one where the lease has terms allowing recovery of the landlord's legal costs, as an administration charge on top of the normal amounts. Therefore, the court did not make a costs order because the landlord already had the means of recovery. As the charge is not being made under a costs order, or a deemed costs order (i.e. the default rules that kick in when no order is made), the procedure for challenging costs orders is not the right one.
During the long and lumbering process of English leasehold reform, there has relatively recently been introduced a way to challenge charges of this kind, including after the event. It was a gap in the law resulting from the charges happening as a result of the lease terms, rather than from the court's own orders. There is a separate means of applying for the lease itself to be varied, which would be in the FTT Property Chamber. However, if I'm right about the scenario in the question, we are talking about a judgment of the County Court that has already happened. In that event, an application can be made to the County Court itself. The relevant statute is paragraph 5A of Schedule 11 to the Commonhold and Leasehold Reform Act 2002 which says:

(1) A tenant of a dwelling in England may apply to the relevant court or tribunal for an order reducing or extinguishing the tenant's liability to pay a particular administration charge in respect of litigation costs.
(2) The relevant court or tribunal may make whatever order on the application it considers to be just and equitable.

and when the litigation costs are in relation to court proceedings, the "relevant court" is that court; or if the proceedings have concluded it is the County Court anyway.
I would like to stop short of pointing out a specific form for making the application, and instead suggest that professional legal advice would be appropriate for somebody in this situation. Such an advisor would  be able to look at the entire situation, not just the summary from which I am making guesses, and consider things like -

what arguments might be made for why the charge should be set aside, what evidence should be given in support, etc.;
the prospects of success weighed against the time and cost of the application;
how to deal with the fact that the mortgage provider has apparently already covered the charge, and changed the total sum owed by the debtor; and
whether any of this would be better handled by negotiation or arbitration outside the courtroom.

